# Tengo una duda con iteradores de istream en C++14

Tags: c++, c++11

Tengo las siguientes líneas:

```
using par = std::pair<std::string, unsigned>;
std::istream& operator>>( std::istream&is, par & p ) {
   is >> p.first >> p.second;
   return is;
}

std::ostringstream out( "qwe 123\nasd 234", std::ios::out | std::ios::in );
std::istream in( out.rdbuf() );

std::copy( std::istream_iterator<par>( in ), std::istream_iterator<par>(),
   std::ostream_iterator<par>( std::cout, "\t" ) );
```

Y no me funciona. ¿Cuál es el problema con este algoritmo?
 Dejo un enlace a un editor y compilador web.
[enlace al ejemplo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8e2fb2d817579e7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es tu `std::istream& operator>>( std::istream&is, par & p )` no está en el namespace std, o en alguno de los namespaces asociados, que es donde se va a buscar siguiendo las reglas del "Argument-dependent lookup" [ADL] (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

Hay un truco que permite al mecanismo de ADL encontrar el tu operador sobrecargado, usando un tipo propio:

```
struct P : par {
    using par::pair;
};
```

Poniendo P en lugar de par, tiene que funcionar. Algo así:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

using word = std::string;
using number = float;

using par = std::pair<word, number>;
using pares = std::vector<par>;


struct P : par {
    using par::pair;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, P const&p)
{
    os << p.first << " " << p.second;
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, P& p)
{
    is >> p.first >> p.second;
    return is;
}



int main()
{

    ostringstream os("qwe 123\nasd 321", ios::out | ios::in);
    istream in(os.rdbuf());

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<P>(in), std::istream_iterator<P>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<P>(std::cout, "\t"));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Me es de gran ayuda. Había leído ese tema, pero no lo había entendido. Gracias.